# Stack overflow error

Tags: c#, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Программа вылетает при выделении памяти под массив (`source = new[3, 4]`)

```
public abstract partial class Matrix<T, U> : 
    ISize<Pair<ulong>>, IEquatable<Matrix<T, U>>, IAddition<Matrix<T, U>>, IMultiply<Matrix<T, U>>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
    where U : UniversalAlgebra.Ring<T>, IEquatable<U>, new()
{
    public Matrix(Pair<ulong> size)
    {
        this.size = size;
        ua = new U();

        source = new T[3, 4]; //Здесь ошибка
    }

    protected Pair<ulong> size;
    public T[,] source;
    protected UniversalAlgebra.Ring<T> ua;
}
```

Причем если конструктор переписать вот так, то память выделится, но при попытке присвоить один массив другому - вновь вылазит переполнение стека:

```
public Matrix(Pair<ulong> size)
{
    this.size = size;
    ua = new U();

    T[,] tmp = new T[3, 4]; //Всё хорошо
    source = tmp; //Вылазит ошибка
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Убрал весь код из Main, и вижу в отладчике вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас написано: public abstract **partial** class Matrix<T, U>. Где вторая часть класса?

Comment: Да, приведите полный стектрейс исключения. Зачастую в ошибке переполнения стека виноват вовсе не самый нижний его элемент...

Comment: var m = new Matrix<double, RealField>(new Pair<ulong>(3, 4));

Comment: Дело в том, что пока это единственная часть класса: другие пока не разработаны. Если отлаживать, то можно увидеть, что другой код не вызывается

Comment: Давайте стек, без него это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: И как мне его получить, если дебаггер после ошибки закрывается?

Comment: Закрывается? о_О Ого. Попробуйте запустить заново Visual Studio и перекомпилировать программу. // Стоп. Не может быть — где-то же вы видите StackOverflowException?

Comment: Уже не раз пробовал. В консоли

Comment: А где вы видите StackOverflowException, если не в отладчике?

Comment: Я попробовал закомментить весь код в main-е и всё равно вижу, что расход памяти процессом - 100%

Comment: @Anaym: Попробуйте соорудить минимальный воспроизводящий пример, чтобы мы могли скомпилировать и воспроизвести у себя. Уберите `abstract partial`, все интерфейсы и `UniversalAlgebra.Ring`, если они не нужны для этого примера.

Comment: Скорее всего это был глюк Visual Studio. После перезагрузки ПК все заработало